# Any backup software for OS X other then Time Machine?

Tags: backup

Time Machine will not backup external disks connected to it.
I need to backup connected external disks.
I have a pile of backup disks in their default formats. Buffalo, WD mostly as backup disks. My external drives include USB drives etc.

Are there any substitutes for Time Machine?

Comment: Judging from your comments to my answer, I think you need to give some more details on your setup and actual problem.

Comment: You could also take a look at SuperDuper http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/13803/superduper! and Carbon Copy Cloner http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7032/carbon-copy-cloner   I've used both but settled on SuperDuper as it does everything I need with a very simple UI

Comment: @amergin Good point. However with neither of these you will get a version history.

Comment: Version history is not necessary. Git is for that internally.

Answer (score 2):

**rsnapshot**

If you really don't want or cannot use Time Machine, you should look into [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org). However, this solution will be much more complicated than using Time Machine. [This guide](https://rayed.com/wordpress/?p=1693) explains the procedure of setup:

1. Use [homebrew](http://brew.sh) for setup: `brew install rsnapshot`
2. Next you will have to configure its settings in `rsnapshot.conf`
3. Now you can run it somewhat like this: `rsnapshot -c rsnapshot.conf hourly`

There is many more guides on how to setup rsnapshot in the internet.

**Time Machine**

Time machine can actually backup external drives. However, external drives are excluded by default. Go to `System Preferences > Time Machine > Options...` and remove your disk from the exclusion list (while the drive is connected). Also the external disk will have to be formatted in HFS+.